# starting google+ hangout and running my application at the same time

Tags: android, android-activity, google-hangouts

iv'e written an Android application which receiving Android GCM messages and communicate with Ardunio ADK board , iv'e started a Google+ hangout (using Google+ application for android) between my android device and my computer and then iv'e started my application so the hangout running in the background and my application in the front but when the hangout running on the background the camera is freezes . the reason for that is as i think is because the hangout activity will pause when i running another application because i can't run two activities at the same time.

**my question** :

**is there is a way so i can run both of them at the same time so i can receive GCM message , communicate with ardunio and make a hangout call at the same time??**

**,  is there is a way to modify  my application to achieve this ??**

**THANKS**